# Standard 2-instantons on the 4-sphere under conformal transformation

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, elliptic-pde, 4-manifolds, conformal-geometry, yang-mills-theory

It is well-known that there is a standard SU(2) 1-instanton on the 4-sphere and any 1-instanton can be obtained from the standard one by conformal transformation. Is there any explicit (family of) "standard" 2-instantons on the 4-sphere so that any 2-instanton is obtained from them by conformal transformation? I heard all 2-instantons are constructed by ADHM construction in an explicit way, but I couldn't find references about conformal transformation on instantons.